How to prompt users to download the PWA on mobile, from a registration link on Desktop?
I'm working on designing a PWA on mental healthcare at work.
I have a hard time imagining a smooth registration/signing-up flow because :

Users will be sent a registration link from their HR team, and will likely use the link on their desktop, at work.

I'm designing mobile first for the MVP and I need users to use their mobile in order to login to the PWA.


I was thinking using a desktop landing page (after registration link)  where I explain the process of downloading the app on their mobile in order to access the full experience, but maybe someone has an easier way to do that or any best practices to share.
Any thoughts ?
Thanks a lot !

You can use a QR code linking to your site. Most phones nowadays have a reader built into their camera app by default, so this should reduce churn.
The user only has to use your app for about 30 seconds for you to have a valid prompt to install the app on their phone as a PWA. If it's a user already interested in using your app, (The HR teams you mentioned early for instance), then those 30 seconds should be no biggy
